# How can I most effectively roll the world?

Tags: dont-starve

I started playing the game Don't Starve yesterday and find it really difficult to get a base set-up. I fear I might have simply rolled a world that is too hard to play.

When starting a new world, what do I want it to include the most of? For example, my current world has a *very large* rock field (30-40 boulders very close to the spawn), a forest of trees and berry shrubs. A huge field of grass (probably close to 100+) — but I'm not seeing many rabbits or any pigmen and beefalos. I start by the swamp (and die often randomly to large tentacles) and there's a graveyard nearby I could farm for tons of research points.

In addition to animals is there anything else I'm missing and might need to have a good "first-time player" world?

Should I just give up and start a new world altogether? If I do what should I be looking for?

Comment: Just a small note, the rabbits are very very easy to catch without traps. So easy infact I don't even see why the traps exist. All you have to do it allign yourself to be between them and their hole and charge in. As long as they are not right next to their hole you can gaurentee a kill.

Comment: Please try again, asking one question at a time :)

Comment: @badp I edited out the first few questions. Can this now be re-opened and I'll ask the other ones separately? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loot that graveyard for research before you decide to move on!

It doesn't sound like you have a terrible world, but also not a super easy one. Having a rock field handy is a bonus, as is having early berries. The only thing you are missing that I find super useful for starting out is a bunch of rabbits.

There are a bunch of other food sources -- perhaps you even have tallbird eggs in your rock field? I'd say try a few games to see if you can get the hang of keeping yourself fed from the other food sources, but if you're just not feeling it, there's no harm in rerolling your world to see if you can't find one more to your liking.

For a first-time player world, food sources are the best things to have nearby, as well as ENOUGH rocks -- at least a fair number of rocks in the fields, if not a biome actually dedicated to them. Graveyards are great and the best way to boost your research quickly and early, but these don't renew in a game, so in the long-term they don't really need to be right by your base. Pigmen are also great if you're planning to make it a long-term game, but if you're just looking to get started, there's no reason they need to be close to your home base. If you happen to start near beefalo, that's great, but they aren't an instant fix for food problems.

Also for players just starting off, swamps are a pain. Tentacles can finish you off very quickly if you don't have armor and get caught by one. A swamp CAN be run through successfully, but in general they are just worse than other biomes near to start.

Comment: Is a swamp useful at all or just a pain? Other than stuff you find in other biomes I just see small ponds with a frog, those tentacles and more spiders than in other areas. Should I craft traps to get rabbits or just hunt them like you mentioned?

Comment: Hunting them is faster and easier in my opinion. They move away from their holes. Move to the opposite side of the hole while keeping your distance. Then click on them to attack such that your path to attack them takes you over their hole. They will run right towards you and you will kill them without issue. Swamps have a few things as you mentioned, frogs and the small ponds (which you can fish from with a fishing pole). Tentacles drop tentacle spikes and tentacle spots when killed, which are of limited usefulness. Swamps aren't terrible, but just generally a little worse than other biomes.

Comment: Is that the only spot you can fish? I figured you could at the edge of the map by the water too

Comment: You cannot fish at the edge of the map, just ponds. Ponds are only found in swamps.

Comment: Ahh, ohh well. Thanks for the help though